# create fake select effect in a <tr> element of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to have this:

[image]

but instead of a select element, I'd need it to be in a div element containing a table with two table cells on each row. So the whole tr> should light up in a similar fashion.

How does one do such a thing in css?

Comment: how far have you tried ... please post the code..

Comment: This is probably something you need javascript for, added tags

Comment: Is there a reason you are not able to use `<select>`? Use the intended means to do your stuff!

Comment: @Sirko: There are two columns of data to show

Comment: Sorry for being unresponsive, something came up that I need to take care of first. I'm very thankful for the two answers and I'll get  back to it as soon as possible! @ Philip: I had some idea's but could come up with anything that actually emulated the select well @Sam Thank you! I actually thought of adding jQuery but didn't want to spam tags as I didn't know if css alone could do this. @ Eric Indeed, thanks for pointing it out while I was unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BF3NE/6/) is a jsFiddle I made. Hope that's what you needed `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You should change class of tr so it will be much easier to do.

**CSS**

```
.selected td {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#id-of-your-table tr td').click(function(){
  $('#id-of-your-table tr').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

and that will be it. Remember I have removed every class from every tr so its only possible to select one. If you want multiple rows than just remove line where removeClass is called for each row and then you can access all rows using jQuery selector.

```
$('#id-of-your-table tr.selected')
```

and you will have all selected rows.

And here it is JS for selecting and deselecting table row and also multiple select.

**JS**

```
$('#id-of-your-table tr td').click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().hasClass('selected'))
     $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
  else
     $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: This wont allow you to uncheck a table row. Perhaps you should edit your answer to include toggle class?